# Is Rxjs timer stop working when user move to another window?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am setting a 60 seconds countdown with rxjs timer on Angular 11. It works fine when I keep that window open. But if I move away (click another tab of the same browser), the timer stops itself after several seconds. There's one time that I wait 3 minutes and get back and see there's 36 seconds left. How is that happening and is there a way to avoid that?

Related function on ts file:

```
countdown: number = 59;
countdownMapping: any = {
        '=9'   : '0#',
        '=8'   : '0#',
        '=7'   : '0#',
        '=6'   : '0#',
        '=5'   : '0#',
        '=4'   : '0#',
        '=3'   : '0#',
        '=2'   : '0#',
        '=1'   : '0#',
        '=0'   : '0#',
        'other': '#'
};


resetResendTimer(clicked) {
        if (this.countdownActive === false) {
            this.countdownActive = true;
            if (clicked) {
                this.otherFunction();
            }
            // Trigger endCountdown after the countdown
            timer(1000, 1000)
                .pipe(
                    finalize(() => {
                        this.endCountdown();
                    }),
                    takeWhile(() => this.countdown > 0),
                    tap(() => this.countdown--)
                )
                .subscribe();
}
```

Related function on html file:

```
Resend verification code 
<span *ngIf="countdownActive">
    (0:{{countdown | i18nPlural: countdownMapping }})
</span>
```

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz demo? This should not be happening :)

Comment: @martin probably not now, I am not that familiar with stackblitz. Maybe I will do that some time later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've seen this behavior on Chrome and it's not related to RXJS, I think it's related to some restrictions applied on background tabs for more performance.

Every tab has a timer budget and this  timer task is allowed to run only when the time budget is non-negative.

check more details here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs#budget-based_background_timer_throttling

Comment: I found that both on chrome and safari, haven't tested on edge and firefox though.